# Images not being affected by CSS under hovering point

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the image that is hovered on larger, and the other two smaller, but only the ones below the hovered image are affected. Please help.

Fiddle here : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rishabh66/hbz9h75d/)

Code here:

```
<img src="http://hornzach.bugs3.com/assets/images/news/blue.png" alt="" width="100" height="96" class="post72914 post72914img1"/><br>
<img src="http://hornzach.bugs3.com/assets/images/news/oak.png" alt="" width="100" height="97" class="post72914 post72914img2"/><br>
<img src="http://hornzach.bugs3.com/assets/images/news/red.png" alt="" width="100" height="92" class="post72914 post72914img3"/>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.post72914 {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
.post72914img1:hover{
    width:210px;
    height:200px;
}
.post72914img2:hover{
    width:210px;
    height:200px;
}
.post72914img3:hover{
    width:210px;
    height:200px;
}

.post72914img1:hover ~ img.post72914img2 {width:50px; height:60px;}
.post72914img1:hover ~ img.post72914img3 {width:50px; height:60px;}
.post72914img2:hover ~ img.post72914img1 {width:50px; height:60px;}
.post72914img2:hover ~ img.post72914img3 {width:50px; height:60px;}
.post72914img3:hover ~ img.post72914img2 {width:50px; height:60px;}
.post72914img3:hover ~ img.post72914img1 {width:50px; height:60px;}
-->
</style>
```

Comment: `~` doesn't look backwards

Comment: Is there a way to make it scan backwards as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another CSS-only answer, with a single wrapping div and a lot less code...

http://jsfiddle.net/94dpn3s4/2/

```
img {    
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;

    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
}

div:hover img {
    height: 50px;
}

div:hover img:hover {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: It has some glitches on hover, I already tried to remove my negative vote, but it gets upvoted instead O

Comment: @dippas I made a minor edit that helps.  I know it's not perfect, but a step in the right direction I think.

Comment: This will be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of your headache with this problem, just use some jquery magic like this:

```
$('.img').hover(
  function(){
      $('.img').not(this).each(function(){
          $(this).stop(true,false).addClass('imgSmall');
      });
  },
  function(){
      $('.img').removeClass('imgSmall');
  }
);
```

[jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bwxf9aer/2/)

If not, then I am sorry and I will delete this answer. I wanted to comment at first, but my reputation hasn't reached 50 yet.